# Method for randomly generating points on surface of sphere don't look random

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot points randomly distributed on the surface of a sphere.

According to numerous [sources](http://extremelearning.com.au/how-to-generate-uniformly-random-points-on-n-spheres-and-n-balls/) (Method 10), the following should generate uniformly randomly distributed points:

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 2000
r = 3
u = np.random.rand(N)
v = np.random.rand(N)
theta = 2*np.pi*u
phi = np.arccos(2*v-1)
x = r*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta)
y = r*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = r*np.cos(theta)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

When I plot it, it doesn't look uniform. Some angles look like this:

[image: this]

whereas others look like this:

[image: this]

Even when I run the code from the website, plotting it looks wrong and non-uniform.

Comment: I think the source you're looking at got phi and theta backward.

Comment: @Mark; the three coordinates are interchangeable for plotting purposes.

Comment: @Prune — this isn't about the coordinates. It's about passing `np.arccos(2*v-1)` to `sin()` instead of `cos()`

Comment: @Mark -- I see: the same phi <-> theta switch as in the posted answer.

Comment: @Prune - yes but the answer is more correct, because it's wrong for z too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source you're looking at got phi and theta switched. Switch them back.